# android_tutorial_teleop building in android studio, Windows

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am working on Windows 7 / Android Studio 1.2.2 / JRE 1.8.0.

Trying to build (android_tutorial_teleop) package in [android_core].
Downloaded source from here.  [link text](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/indigo)

Imported [android_core] in Android Studio.
Selected (android_tutorial_teleop)  in "Selelct Run/Debug Configuration".
And pressed green "Run" button.
It build and launched in emulator.

**[1]**
In emulator.  This app is executed.
Entered host IP address and pressed "Connect" button.
But it crashed.

**[2]**
I copied "android_tutorial_teleop-debug.apk" to my android phone. (from ../build/output/apk/)
Installed it.  Executed App.
Entered host IP address and pressed "Connect" button.
But it crashed also.

I searched similar issues in "answers.ros.org".  but couldn't find solution.
I think "rosjava_core" is needed. But I don't know how to make it in Android Studio in Windows 7.
What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214723/android_tutorial_teleop--building-in-android-studio,-windows/) by [erenes](https://answers.ros.org/users/23379/erenes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-28**:
Is there a reason you aren't using Linux? Windows is not entirely supported in ROS (at least to my knowledge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you.  Yes. ROS is basically based on Linux.
Anyway I solved this issue. Searched and read other developers writing.

I need  "  ", for following.  without it, the app crashed.

export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://192.168.178.21:11311"
export ROS_HOSTNAME="192.168.178.21"

---

Originally posted by [erenes](https://answers.ros.org/users/23379/erenes/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0